# SPContentTypeId.Empty vs default

Tags: development, content-type, ssom, c-sharp

Is there any reason to prefer `SPContentTypeId.Empty` over `default`?

```
Console.WriteLine(default (SPContentTypeId)); // writes 0x
Console.WriteLine(new SPContentTypeId()); // writes 0x
Console.WriteLine(SPContentTypeId.Empty); // writes 0x00C2208B8CE6E1422CADC1C521EAB2A68B
```

Answer (score 2):

`SPContentTypeId.Empty` is used to indicate and check that a content type has no id (yet), for example, one of the `SPContentType` constructors

```
SPContentType(SPContentType parentContentType, SPContentTypeCollection collection, string name)
```

defined as

```
public SPContentType(SPContentType parentContentType, SPContentTypeCollection collection, string name) : this(SPContentTypeId.Empty, parentContentType, collection)
{
    this.Initialize(parentContentType, collection, name);
}
```

or in another method

```
private SPContentType(SPContentTypeId contentTypeId, SPContentType parentContentType, SPContentTypeCollection cts)
```

you find code like

```
if ((parentContentType == null) && contentTypeId.Equals(SPContentTypeId.Empty))
{
    parentContentType = cts.Web.AvailableContentTypes[SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Item];
}
if ((parentContentType == null) && contentTypeId.Equals(SPContentTypeId.Empty))
{
    this.m_id = NewContentTypeId();
}
else if ((parentContentType == null) && !contentTypeId.Equals(SPContentTypeId.Empty))
{
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

`SPContentTypeId` is not a nullable type. Therefore, you cannot initialize an instance of it as  null. So instead you can assign it as `SPContentTypeId.Empty` , which is equivalent to empty content type.

```
    // SPContentTypeId ctId = null;//Throws build error as not nullable 
    //  SPContentTypeId ctId= string.Empty;//Throws build error as not type is not a string
   SPContentTypeId ctId = SPContentTypeId.Empty;
```

Comment: You can create struct instance with `SPContentTypeId ctId = new SPContentTypeId()` and it's not the same as `SPContentTypeId.Empty`.  What are the cases when `empty content type` comes to play?

Comment: I would imagine that Empty would be used to initialize an object prior to code that may not always generate an ID, such as looping through a list of objects containing content type Ids and trying to match one of them. It would be convenient to just check if the ID is still empty, rather than adding a boolean if an ID was found or storing the initial value of `SPContentTypeId()` and comparing that further along the line.